# Can't access port 25 on my azure VM from my server

Tags: azure, windows-server-2012

I set up a linux vm on azure which runs my program that is listening for incoming smtp traffic on port 25.
The vm uses the resource group model and I opened port 25 (inbound) at the nsg attached to this VM.

I also have a physical server (not on azure) so I used https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ in order to make sure that port 25 is really open and it says it is.

So far so good, the problem is that I can't connect to this VM from my physical windows server, I opened it port 25 (outbound) but yet when I check with PortQRY.exe (microsoft tool) I get `TCP port 25 (smtp service): FILTERED`

So it seems like the problem is on my physical server, I tried also disabling my firewall (for private and public connections) but still I get the same output from PortQRY.

What can be the cause? and how can it be solved?

Comment: This sounds like a network configuration issue with your physical server. You may want to check with your Network Admins to see if they are blocking outbound communications to Port 25 from your corporate network. They likely are to avoid their computers becoming email spam botnets.

Comment: Aside from this likely being the issue @ChrisPietschmann described, this type of question belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

This is because Microsoft decided to block port # 25 in Azure for the subscriptions signed up after November 2017. You should use a subscription older than November 15'2017 to your requirement based on port 25
([Azure is committed to stopping SPAM and reducing the customer impact caused by negative IP reputation.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2017/11/15/enhanced-azure-security-for-sending-emails-november-2017-update/))

Ref : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2017/11/15/enhanced-azure-security-for-sending-emails-november-2017-update/